# Multi Series Graph on Excel for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I'm trying to fit twelve different series on a scatter plot with x and y variables. Excel doesn't seem to recognize this. How do I design this graph? All I keep getting is this:

[image]

Comment: To post an image, use the Insert Image button on the toolbar in the editor and follow the prompts to upload an image. If you need help with formatting, see the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).